# JSF with External Resource Bundle

Tags: jsf-2, resourcebundle

I'm doing a JSF 2.0 application on Tomcat 6.x. I have a resource bundle in different languages, is it possible to externalize the properties files outside the webapp?

For the moment I have this in my faces-config.xml:

```
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>fr</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>front</base-name>
        <var>messages</var>
    </resource-bundle>
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely possible. To the point, just put the files in the classpath. You can do that by placing it in any of existing paths covered by the webapp's runtime classpath, or by adding the new path to the webapp's runtime classpath.

You could add a new path to the classpath by specifying it in `shared.loader` of Tomcat's `/conf/catalina.properties`. Assuming that you've placed `front*.properties` files in `/var/webapp/conf` folder, then you need to specify the `shared.loader` as follows:

```
shared.loader = /var/webapp/conf
```

Comment: hey @BalusC one question. suppose my properties files are at C:/Program File/My app/front.properties. I have "shared.loader = C:/Program File/My app" is that ok? the base-name of the resource bundle would still be just "front"?

Comment: If a path contains spaces, you need to quote the path. I.e. `shared.loader = "C:/Program File/My app"`. By the way, it's by default "Program Files", not "Program File".

Comment: I tried using the quotes but Tomcat would not start anymore, it throws this exception: "Class loader creation threw exception java.io.IOException: The name of the file, directory or volume is not valid" any idea why? I'm using Tomcat 6.0.32. I had get rid of spaces C:/Progra~1/MyApp

Answer (score 0):

May be because of the spaces in the folder name; try to put the resource bundle file in another place, eg.: `c:/temp/resources/`